# How to populate an UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to display my array in an UITableView, but I can't do it properly. It is not displaying the labels text and the labels are blank. Here's what I've done so far. Only the image is being displayed at my UITableView

```
NSMutableArray *opp;
NSMutableArray *prop;
NSMutableArray *checkA = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *values = [dict allValues];
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];

NSArray *games = [values valueForKey:@"Game"];
count = [[games objectAtIndex:0]count];
NSUInteger index = 0;
while (index < count) {
    Opponent = [[[[[games objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Opponent"]objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"OpponentName"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    [opp addObject:Opponent];

    Proponent = [[[[[games objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Proponent"]objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"ProponentName"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    [prop addObject:Proponent];
index++
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
switch(section)
{
    case 0:  return 2;  // section 0 has 2 rows
    case 1:  return 1;  // section 1 has 1 row
    default: return 0;
};
}

// Return the row for the corresponding section and row
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cells" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 50)];
[images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[cell addSubview:images];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(131, 27, 59, 21)];
label1.text = [opp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label1];
NSLog(@"label 1: ",label1.text);
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(231, 27, 67, 21)];
label2.text = [prop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label2];
NSLog(@"label 2: ",label2.text);

return cell;
}
```

Now it is working, forgot to init my string. The issue now is it is only displaying 3 rows. I am expecting 29 rows because my opp has 29 objects

Comment: try this code  [cell.contentView addSubview: label1]; ya change your label position

Comment: Now it is working, but it is only displaying 3 rows. I am expecting 29 rows cause my opp has 29 objects

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need sections because you are not dealing with them anywhere, so remove `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method and return 'count' in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. By default number of sections will be 1. Refer below code,

```
NSMutableArray *opp;
NSMutableArray *prop;
NSMutableArray *checkA = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *values = [dict allValues];
NSArray *keys = [dict allKeys];

NSArray *games = [values valueForKey:@"Game"];
count = [[games objectAtIndex:0]count];
NSUInteger index = 0;
while (index < count) {
    Opponent = [[[[[games objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Opponent"]objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"OpponentName"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    [opp addObject:Opponent];

    Proponent = [[[[[games objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"Proponent"]objectAtIndex:index]valueForKey:@"ProponentName"]valueForKey:@"text"];
    [prop addObject:Proponent];
index++
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
return count;
}

// Return the row for the corresponding section and row
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cells" forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *images = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, 50, 50)];
[images setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[img objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[cell addSubview:images];

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(131, 27, 59, 21)];
label1.text = [opp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label1];
NSLog(@"label 1: ",label1.text);
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(231, 27, 67, 21)];
label2.text = [prop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell addSubview:label2];
NSLog(@"label 2: ",label2.text);

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code because you are pass static row value in table

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return count;
}
```